# What is wrong with this Asynchronus task?

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

the method onPostExecute simply was not executed, I have seen 36 at LogCat but I can not see 13 in LogCAT. I tried to debug it, it seemed that it goes to the first line of the class (package line) after return statement.

```
private class Client extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> {
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            Log.e(TAG,10+"");
            try {
                socket = new Socket(target, port);
                //socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
                Log.e(TAG,31+"");
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                Log.e(TAG,34+"");
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Log.e(TAG,35+"");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e(TAG,36+"");
            return 1;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Log.e(TAG,13+"");
            try {
                Log.e(TAG,12+"");
                oos.writeUTF(key);
                Log.e(TAG,16+"");
                if (ois.readInt() == OKAY) {
                    isConnected = true;
                    Log.e(TAG,14+"");
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG,15+"");
                    isConnected = false;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isClosed = true;
            }
            Log.e(TAG,19+"");
        }
    }
```

Number seen in logCat:

```
10
31
34
35
36
```

Nothing after that.

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your question a bit? For example, this sentence makes no sense to me: " I have seen 16 at LogCat but I can not see 16 in LogCAT". Your logging doesn't seem very helpful either, since you print the same number at various points in the execution, which makes it harder to track the flow of the code.

Comment: okay I have changed numbers, but still same. The problem is; after execution of doInBackground, onPostExecute is never called.

PS: when I switch these two lines, second one is also never executed, it looks it paused after first initialization. These lines are:
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

Comment: Wait, do you see 13 and 12? I assumed you did. - add in a copy of the numbers and their order that you see.

Comment: there should be no reason why you shouldn't be getting 13 or 12 or 19 as long as you are executing using client.execute() to start the thread and you are never calling client.cancel()

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you call doInBackground() directly? You should call it via new Client().execute(Integer...)

Comment: it is called as Client().execute(Integer...) but I dont know what is the problem, and how I fixed this also. I think, I just rewrote from strach and that fixed it. but not sure.